# What kind of pipe insulation is appropriate for sun exposure?

Tags: plumbing, insulation, outdoor

I want to insulate a water line outdoors, where it will be exposed to sun. I expect that UV light will damage many foam pipe insulations over time.

Is there a type of insulation that will tolerate the exposure? Or should I plan to cover the insulation with another material to protect it?

Answer (score 2):

Use a rockwool tube insulation which will withstand exterior conditions. It's sold covered with reflexive aluminium foil and it's usually enough.
Adding more shielding depends on how mechanically 'aggressive' conditions are present (walking by people, animals, traffic etc.).